# random number from 0 to 20 that jumps 4 times

Tags: iphone, cocoa, random, nsarray, range

HI 
i'm stock with generating a random number
I have an array that holds 20 variables, and i want to choose randomly within that range with a condition that it jumps every 4 variables. the random number should be either (0 , 4, 8, 12 or 16)?? how can I do that ? 
my array of type NSArray...

Thanks,

Comment: You could just choose a random number 0,1,2,3,4 and then multiply by 4.  Note that if you repeat this, you will still be restriced to the same five variables from your array.

Comment: Checkout my answer. only one line :)

Comment: hey @Dalal Chetan Bhalara Done just copy and paste from my answer. i posted answer before him. plz check the time of given answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int random = (arc4random() % 5)*4;
```

Comment: int random = ((arc4random() % 5)+1)*4; it will give 4,8,12,16,20.

Answer (score 1):

Use below block of code

```
int randomNum;
do 
{
  randomNum = arc4random() % 17; //Ensure --> Your number will be in the range (0-16)
}while(randomNum % 4 == 0) //Must be the multiple of 4 means ----> { 0,4,8,12,16}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int r = arc4random() % 20;` for getting the random number. Then by the time you want to get another random number check the previous number that you obtained and use it according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to store your "random numbers" into a

**new  NSArray: [0 , 4, 8, 12, 16]**.

Then you can generate a **standard random integer** such as

```
int r = arc4random() % 5;
```

in the range of 0 to 4 and indirectly retrieve your desired "random numbers" from the defined NSArray.

Otherwise, you can use power or other arithmetic calculation to get your desired output etc, but why waste the effort of calculation if you know there's only 5 candidates you wanted?

Comment: I think that in this case storing an array of "random" no's and indexing ramdonly into them isnt the best soloution. Given that the set of random no's he wants is regular then the arithmetic soloution seems the clearest to me.

Comment: depending on his objectives I guess. I think both ways work, one induces Array lookup and space, another one .... oh yea. agree

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
NSArray *numbers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:8],[NSNumber numberWithInt:16],nil];

int myRandom0to16 = [[numbers objectAtIndex:arc4random()%numbers.count] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

int random = (arc4random() % 5)*4;

For Ex-

if random no is 0 then you get 0 * 4 = 0

if random no is 1 then you get 1 * 4 = 4

if random no is 2 then you get 2 * 4 = 8